# PUBLIC | PRIVATE | INTERFACE cmake как понимать данные спецификаторы

Tags: cmake

Я продолжаю разбираться с cmake файлами, и появился вопрос для чего используются спецификаторы PUBLIC | PRIVATE | INTERFACE ? Из прочтенной справки [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/target_link_libraries.html?highlight=target_link_libraries) я мало что понял...

> The PUBLIC, PRIVATE and INTERFACE keywords can be used to specify both
>   the link dependencies and the link interface in one command. Libraries
>   and targets following PUBLIC are linked to, and are made part of the
>   link interface. Libraries and targets following PRIVATE are linked to,
>   but are not made part of the link interface. Libraries following
>   INTERFACE are appended to the link interface and are not used for
>   linking .

Я не совсем пойму что имеется ввиду когда говорится что они связаны (имеется ввиду линковщик ?) и являются/не являются частью связанного интерфейса (тоже не совсем пойму) так же непонятно касательно INTERFACE где пишется что они присоединяются к интерфейсу ссылки и не используются для связи с целью (linking ).

Подскажите что имеется ввиду в cmake файлах когда мы указываем данные модификаторы ? Имеется ли ввиду что таким образом мы устанавливаем необходимые файлы (заголовки к примеру для библилотек) или же библиотеки (к примеру в случае с (*.so) библиотеками) для работы программы ? Но программа и так не сможет запуститься без использования (*.so) библиотеки к примеру... Меня несколько запутали данные модификаторы.

Так же не понятно к их использование в команде [target_sources](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/target_sources.html) да и в целом не совсем пойму их смысл в cmake файлах. Буду благодарен если разъясните для чего они нужны и когда к ним стоит прибегать.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Там всё достаточно просто.

1. `PRIVATE` служит для того, чтобы указать какие элементы (исходники, библиотеки, цели) необходимы для сборки этой цели. Т.е. эта цель зависима от этих элементов, но другие цели, которые будут использовать эту цель в качестве зависимости, не получат её зависимости транзитивно. Т.е. если цель `A` зависит от нашей цели `Target`, у которой в качестве *приватной* зависимости указана цель `Dep`, то `A` не будет зависеть от `Dep`, а `Target` будет использовать `Dep` при сборке себя.
2. `INTERFACE` служит для указания элементов, которые не нужны для сборки этой цели, но они должны быть «прокинуты» для любой цели, которая данную цель указывает в качестве зависимости. Т.е. если цель `A` зависит от нашей цели `Target`, у которой в качестве *интерфейсной* зависимости указана цель `Dep`, то `A` будет зависеть от `Dep`, но `Target` не будет использовать `Dep` при сборке себя.
3. `PUBLIC` аналогичен связке `INTERFACE` и `PRIVATE`. Т.е. если цель `A` зависит от нашей цели `Target`, у которой в качестве *публичной* зависимости указана цель `Dep`, то `A` будет зависеть от `Dep`, а `Target` будет использовать `Dep` при сборке себя.

Прибегать к ним стоит тогда, когда нужно. Это сравнительно новые модификаторы, которые лучше всего раскрывают себя при разработке библиотек. Т.е. они позволяют чётко разграничить, что мы показываем миру и что от чего зависит. Для себя можно взять за правило использовать `PRIVATE` по умолчанию, прибегая к другим модификаторам только тогда, когда они действительно необходимы.

Answer (score 7):

Под *link interface* (*интерфейс линковки* или *интерфейс связывания*, для любителей родного языка) в `cmake` понимается список библиотек/флагов линковки, которые будут также добавлены при линковке данной цели. На практике это выражается в свойствах цели [`INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES.html) (или [`LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/prop_tgt/LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES.html) для более старых версий `cmake`).

Например, пусть будет такая структура в `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library (foo SHARED foo.c)
target_link_libraries (foo PUBLIC z)

add_executable (foo-exe foo-main.c)
target_link_libraries (foo-exe foo)
```

В этом случае с `zlib` будут линковаться и `foo`, и `foo-exe`, команды линковки будут выглядеть примерно так:

```
cc ... -o libfoo.so foo.c.o -lz
cc ... foo-main.c.o  -o foo-exe -l./libfoo.so -lz
```

При использовании `target_link_libraries (foo PRIVATE z)` только сама библиотека будет слинкована с `zlib`:

```
cc ... -o libfoo.so foo.c.o -lz
cc ... foo-main.c.o  -o foo-exe -l./libfoo.so
```

А при `target_link_libraries (foo INTERFACE z)` — только `foo-exe`:

```
cc ... -o libfoo.so foo.c.o
cc ... foo-main.c.o  -o foo-exe -l./libfoo.so -lz
```

т.е. зависимости указанные в `INTERFACE` и `PUBLIC` становятся транзитивными данной цели и передаются другим; а те что указаны в `PRIVATE` и `PUBLIC` используются для линковки самой цели.

---

Обычно на практике для библиотек стоит указывать `PUBLIC`, для флагов линковки — `PRIVATE`; `INTERFACE` используется намного реже, когда нужно сделать что-то хитрое и писать немного меньше в скриптах.

---

Для `target_sources()` всё аналогично: для `PUBLIC` и `INTERFACE` исходник будет использоваться при сборке зависимой цели, как если бы он был указан в её собственном `target_sources()`; только вот практического смысла (не считая некоторого сомнительного комфорта в IDE) использовать что-либо кроме `PRIVATE` почти никогда нет...